# Iterating through a nested dictionary to check if a particular value is all numerical letters

Tags: python, iteration

the following is a subset of a really large nested dictionary that I have:

```
{
 '1': {'Name': 'Katherine Watson',
       'Age': '1',
       'Height': '150'},
 '2': {'Name': 'Emilia Li',
       'Age': '56',
       'Height': '175'},
 '3': {'Name': 'Dorothy Johnson',
       'Age': '29',
       'Height': '162'},
 '4': {'Name': 'Alexandar Knight',
       'Age': '14',
       'Height': '164r'}
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a function that will iterate through the specific key ('Height'), which then returns the corresponding value if it's all numerical numbers or None otherwise.
E.g. the dictionary with ID'1' should return '150' for the height. But the dictionary with ID'4' should return None for the height.

Here's a code I've written but it only returns '150' instead of iterating through all the IDs and returning '150' '175' '162' 'None'.

```
data = {
 '1': {'Name': 'Katherine Watson',
       'Age': '1',
       'Height': '150'},
 '2': {'Name': 'Emilia Li',
       'Age': '56',
       'Height': '175'},
 '3': {'Name': 'Dorothy Johnson',
       'Age': '29',
       'Height': '162'},
 '4': {'Name': 'Alexandar Knight',
       'Age': '14',
       'Height': '164r'}
}

def person_height(height):
    for some_id, info in data.items():
        if info['Height'].isnumeric():
            return info['Height']
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO, please showcase your attempts in solving the problem.

Comment: Your dict is nested so you need ```info['Height']```
Don't use reserved keywords such as ```id```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to store your results in a "clean" dictionary, you will need as many nested loops as nested dictionaries you have. So:

```py
def check_height(your_dict):
    new_clean_dict = {}
    for a, b in your_dict.items():
        for e, f in b.items():
            if e == 'Height' and f.isdigit():
               new_clean_dict[a] = {'Height': f} 
            else:
               new_clean_dict[a] = {'Height': None}
    return new_clean_dict
```

This will produce a new dictionary with the same root key and with a value for each key that is a nested dictionary with only the key `Height`.
In order to get the results:

```py
new_clean_dict = check_height(your_dict)
```

Comment: @Tabata I have re-edited my answer to produce a new dictionary instead of a list, following your last comment up.

Comment: There's really no need to loop through the contents of each inner dictionary if you already know which key you want; just access it directly.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but if the dictionary is not consistent and the key is missing it will fail

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend `.get()` instead of looping.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isdigit`

```
data = {
 '1': {'Name': 'Katherine Watson',
       'Age': '1',
       'Height': '150'},
 '2': {'Name': 'Emilia Li',
       'Age': '56',
       'Height': '175'},
 '3': {'Name': 'Dorothy Johnson',
       'Age': '29',
       'Height': '162'},
 '4': {'Name': 'Alexandar Knight',
       'Age': '14',
       'Height': '164r'}
}

def person_height(height):
    if height.isdigit():
        return height

for some_id, info in data.items():
    print("\nID:", some_id)
    print("Height:", person_height(info['Height']))
```

Output:

```
ID: 1
Height: 150

ID: 2
Height: 175

ID: 3
Height: 162

ID: 4
Height: None
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for your reply! I tried rewriting your code to get it all into one function (as seen in the code I've pasted at the top). The problem I'm having is that it is stopping after the first iteration (ID: 1). Could I possibly get some pointers as to why this is happening?

Comment: @Hi David, apologies I've edited my question so it should now show the code I've written... (it's on the top of this page)

Comment: @Tabata
You are returning the first result.
You can return a list with all results etc..

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine actually but `return` will break the loop immediately and return the first result only so just turn your `return` to `print()` will do the work.

Another way is save the result to a list first and read them later:

```
data = {
 '1': {'Name': 'Katherine Watson',
       'Age': '1',
       'Height': '150'},
 '2': {'Name': 'Emilia Li',
       'Age': '56',
       'Height': '175'},
 '3': {'Name': 'Dorothy Johnson',
       'Age': '29',
       'Height': '162'},
 '4': {'Name': 'Alexandar Knight',
       'Age': '14',
       'Height': '164r'}
}

def person_height(data):
    height_list = []
    for some_id, info in data.items():
        if info['Height'].isnumeric():
            height_list.append(info['Height'])
        else:
            height_list.append(None)
    return height_list

for height in person_height(data):
    print(height)
```

Output:

```
150
175
162
None
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with a [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).

```
def get_heights(data):
    return [int(person['Height'])
            if person['Height'].isdigit()
            else None
            for person in data.values()]

print(get_heights(data))
```

Running it with your sample data outputs:

```
[150, 175, 162, None]
```

Since you're not using the IDs, you can use `.values()` instead of `.items()`. And in your code, you named the argument `height` but then refer to `data` in the function body. This means that it doesn't matter what you supply as the argument; the code only works because it's referring back to the globally defined variable, which happens to have the same name.

I've also converted the heights to integers, even though you didn't specifically request that.